# OpenAI GPT-3 API: How does it count tokens for different languages?

Tags: nlp, tokenize, openai-api, gpt-3

We all know that GPT-3 models can accept and produce all kinds of languages such as English, French, Chinese, Japanese and so on.

In traditional NLP, different languages have different token-making methods.

- For those Alphabetic Languages such as English, `Bert` use BPE method to make tokens like below:

```
Insomnia caused much frustration.
==>
In-, som-, nia, caus-, ed, much, frus-, tra-, tion, .,
```

- For those Charactaristic Languages such as Chinese or Japanese, just use the character itself as the token like below.

```
東京メトロは心に寄り添う
==>
東, 京, メ, ト, ロ, は, 心, に, 寄, り, 添, う,
```

```
我说你倒是快点啊！！！
==>
我, 说, 你, 倒, 是, 快, 点, 啊, ！, ！, ！,
```

But for GPT-3, it composes of different languages and can produce both Chinese and English in one sentence. So I am really curious how this model makes tokens.

Answer (score 4):

Use the [Tokenizer](https://platform.openai.com/tokenizer) to understand how a piece of text would be tokenized by the OpenAI API.

For example, `Insomnia caused much frustration.` would be tokenized as 6 tokens.

[image: Example 1]

Whereas, `我说你倒是快点啊！！!` would be tokenized as 27 tokens with a slight note at the bottom:

> **Note**: Your input contained one or more unicode characters that map to
> multiple tokens. The output visualization may display the bytes in
> each token in a non-standard way.

[image: Example 2]

Comment: But I am still confused about the Chinese and other Unicode charactors such as emojis, Japanese, Korean characters when tokenizing. cause the code is written in [tokenizer](https://github.com/huggingface/tokenizers) in Rust.

Comment: Hm, I searched a bit, but found nothing special other than [this](https://github.com/openai/CLIP/issues/7).

Comment: Thank you very much still. Cause I tried chatgpt and it can smoothly handle both chinese and english in only one reply.so I am really curious about thetokenization method. Cause I assume it must be different from the originl chinese character tokenization.

Comment: I find facebook provide an open source repo [muse](https://github.com/facebookresearch/MUSE), which might be thought provoking.

Comment: How could it help you to figure out OpenAI API tokenization?

Comment: It doesnt help me. It use a different way from BPE token generation.

Answer (score 1):

Use tiktoken ^^
https://cookbook.openai.com/examples/how_to_count_tokens_with_tiktoken

```py
# https://cookbook.openai.com/examples/how_to_count_tokens_with_tiktoken

import tiktoken


def num_tokens_from_messages(messages, model="gpt-3.5-turbo-0613"):
    """Return the number of tokens used by a list of messages."""
    try:
        encoding = tiktoken.encoding_for_model(model)
    except KeyError:
        print("Warning: model not found. Using cl100k_base encoding.")
        encoding = tiktoken.get_encoding("cl100k_base")
    if model in {
        "gpt-3.5-turbo-0613",
        "gpt-3.5-turbo-16k-0613",
        "gpt-4-0314",
        "gpt-4-32k-0314",
        "gpt-4-0613",
        "gpt-4-32k-0613",
    }:
        tokens_per_message = 3
        tokens_per_name = 1
    elif model == "gpt-3.5-turbo-0301":
        tokens_per_message = 4  # every message follows <|start|>{role/name}\n{content}<|end|>\n
        tokens_per_name = -1  # if there's a name, the role is omitted
    elif "gpt-3.5-turbo" in model:
        print("Warning: gpt-3.5-turbo may update over time. Returning num tokens assuming gpt-3.5-turbo-0613.")
        return num_tokens_from_messages(messages, model="gpt-3.5-turbo-0613")
    elif "gpt-4" in model:
        print("Warning: gpt-4 may update over time. Returning num tokens assuming gpt-4-0613.")
        return num_tokens_from_messages(messages, model="gpt-4-0613")
    else:
        raise NotImplementedError(
            f"""num_tokens_from_messages() is not implemented for model {model}. See https://github.com/openai/openai-python/blob/main/chatml.md for information on how messages are converted to tokens."""
        )
    num_tokens = 0
    for message in messages:
        num_tokens += tokens_per_message
        for key, value in message.items():
            num_tokens += len(encoding.encode(value))
            if key == "name":
                num_tokens += tokens_per_name
    num_tokens += 3  # every reply is primed with <|start|>assistant<|message|>
    return num_tokens
```